# Should 'apt-get upgrade' be run before 'apt-get dist-upgrade'

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates

Many times I have seen people upgrading the packages on their system, and I have noticed that some of them specifically run:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Before running:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Is this really necessary? Doesn't running `dist-upgrade` cover what `upgrade` does and more? Or is there some real reason to run the `upgrade` command before the `dist-upgrade` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not necessary and from my experience, I can confirm that.

Everything else is superstition, just as the claim that I must re-start my system when a configuration has been changed. 
Perhaps you then feel better, but it's not necessary. But that's another story. **;)**

---

From `man apt-get`

> dist-upgrade **in addition to performing the function of upgrade**,
>   also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of
>   packages

Comment: Well, there was actually one occasion where I changed a configuration file, I didn't get what I wanted until a restart, which I found rather annoying because it didn't even tell me that it needed a restart! :D

Comment: @ParanoidPanda We should examine more closely. =)

Comment: Perhaps, if I remember what it was! ;D

Comment: Though it is not the question, one should add that `apt-get update` should be run before `apt-get dist-upgrade`. It is easy to get confused between all these updates and upgrades.

Comment: @user68186: Yes, in fact I think that `apt-get` should have a built in command that runs `update` and then `dist-upgrade`.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda http://askubuntu.com/q/672223/367165